# Как прочитать файл в нестандартной кодировке на Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

очень заинтересовал flutter и dart, начал изучать язык и технологию, но появляются проблемы в самых неожиданных местах.
Не являюсь программистом, скорее использую языки программирования для решения задач учёта и автоматизации время от времени. Прошу прощения за вопрос - вероятно, для специалиста он смешной, но рискну...

Неожиданно наткнулся на следующую проблему: не нашел, как в dart прочитать файл в кодировке UTF-16LE. Не сомневаюсь, что он есть(этот способ), но у меня, как у новичка, возникла проблема. Да, избаловал меня python, где таких проблем я не встречал.

Похоже, dart может в базе работать с текстовыми файлами только в кодировке UTF-8.

Есть ли какой-нибудь простой способ это сделать?
Если можно, поделитесь кодом.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть довольно старенькая, но пока ещё работоспособная библиотека [Utf](https://pub.dev/packages/utf), вот пример её использования:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:utf/utf.dart';

main() async {
  var file = File("test.utf.16le");
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  var content = decodeUtf16le(bytes);
  print("$content");
}
```

Но т.к. **dart**-строки хранятся в памяти в кодировке UTF-16, то довольно просто прочитать файл без всяких дополнителных библиотек, с одним только условием, что платформа на которой запускается код использует порядок байтов LE (little-endian используется практически на всех настолных компьютерах). В противном случае пары байтов нужно поменять местами.

Пример без использования сторонних библиотек:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

main() async {
  var file = File("test.utf.16le");
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  var codes = Uint16List.view(bytes.buffer);
  var content = String.fromCharCodes(codes);
  print("$content");
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас. За помощь и код. Все действительно работает.